# Subdomain redirection and URL not chaging

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, subdomain

I'm using godaddy to redirect with masking from http://myshop-123.com (a shopify webstore) to http://eu.myshop.com.

I want the URL bar to change when the user navigates in the page. For example, when user navigates to the page product_1.html, I want the browser's URL bar to show http://eu.myshop.com/product_1.html, which currently is not happening since the URL bar shows only http://eu.myshop.com/ no matter what.

As far I've seen in the source of the http://eu.myshop.com when loaded, the page is being loaded in a frame:

```
<html>
 <head>...</head>
 <frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
 <frame src="http://myshop-123.com" frameborder="0">
  #document
 </frame>
 <frame ..>
 </frame>
</html>
```

How can I make the subdomain show the changes in the URL bar when the user navigates the page?

I have even tried to manipulate the browser history with the [HTML5 pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history), but still no results and I guess because of the godaddy's redirection and frame.

*(note: the links are fictitious).*

Comment: Like you said, your site `http://myshop-123.com` is in a frame and you navigate in it. But your main page is `http://eu.myshop.com/` and you stay on it : So it is normal that you browser show you only that URL. You want the address bar to show `http://eu.myshop.com/product_1.html` but is this a real page, or does it show a 404 ?

Comment: `http://eu.myshop.com/product_1.html` would map an existing `http://myshop-123.com/product_1.html`. I want to have the subdomain redirection with masking and at the same time keep the changes in the URL so the user does not get confused when navigating on the page.

Comment: When you say *"the URL bar shows only http://eu.myshop.com/ no matter what"* do you mean that the actual URL of the page is http://eu.myshop.com/product_1.html but the browser is only showing http://eu.myshop.com/? I ask because some browsers now show only the hostname that you are on, not the full URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myshop-123.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://eu.myshop.com/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Since I'm using godaddy for the redirection and Shopify for storing and serving the content, where would I edit the .htaccess file? I don't have access to the server.

Comment: How can you use GoDaddy for the redirection if you don't have access to the server ? You don't do a redirection there, you display a page with frames. You can upload files on your site, right ?